# Using iDangero.us swiper inside collapsible elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

I've tried to add multiple instance of Swiper on a page which work fine except the ones that are inside collapsible containers (Bootstrap or jQuery mobile).  Only the Swiper on first panel which is visible works well and the rest don't.

It looks that Swiper can't initialize if the parent container is not visible.  Would appreciate any workarounds.

Here is example code:

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
      <div class="swiper-container" id="sec1">
        <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
        <div class="swiper-title">Section 1 header</div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide" style="width:1250px;">
              <div>
                slide 1
              </div>
              <div>
                slide 2
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
      <div class="swiper-container" id="sec2">
        <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
        <div class="swiper-title">Section 2 header</div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide" style="width:1250px;">
              <div>
                slide 1
              </div>
              <div>
                slide 2
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
      <div class="swiper-container" id="sec3">
        <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
        <div class="swiper-title">Section 3 header</div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide" style="width:1250px;">
              <div>
                slide 1
              </div>
              <div>
                slide 2
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

```
$( ".swiper-container" ).each(function( index ) {
  var mySwiperScroll = ('#' + $(this).attr("id") + ' .swiper-scrollbar');
  //alert(mySwiperScroll);
  var mySwiper = new Swiper(this,{
    scrollContainer: true,
    scrollbar: {
      container:  mySwiperScroll
    }
  })
```

});

Comment: Kindly provide some code to look into. Please provide code that you have tried till now along with your question as it helps the users in giving answers.

Comment: I've added the code.  Only the swiper on the first/visible panel work, the rest don't.

Answer (score 0):

That is right. Swiper will not be initialized in invisible elements. You should just reInit swiper that is inside of collapsible when you expand it. There is a special event for this in jQuery mobile http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-expand

Comment: I've already tried that method but still didn't manage to initialize the Swiper again.  Maybe I am doing something wrong.  Would appreciate if you have a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/2gQ4E/5/   sec2 function is firing after expand but swiper is not initialized.